# Как удалить ненужные строки в Pandas по условиям

Tags: python, pandas, анализ-данных

Дан df:

```
a = pd.DataFrame([{'id': 1, 'b': 1, 'd': 0},
                  {'id': 1, 'b': 2, 'd': 0},
                  {'id': 1, 'b': 2, 'd': 1},
                  {'id': 1, 'b': 2, 'd': 0},
                  {'id': 1, 'b': 2, 'd': 0},
                  {'id': 1, 'b': 2, 'd': 0},
                  {'id': 1, 'b': 4, 'd': 0},

                  {'id': 2, 'b': 1, 'd': 1},
                  {'id': 2, 'b': 2, 'd': 0},
                  {'id': 2, 'b': 2, 'd': 0},
                  {'id': 2, 'b': 2, 'd': 0},
                  {'id': 2, 'b': 2, 'd': 0},
                  {'id': 2, 'b': 2, 'd': 1},
                  {'id': 2, 'b': 4, 'd': 0},])
```

Как можно у каждого`id` и в строке, где `b == 1`, проверить столбец `d` если он != 0, то удалить все строки с этим id, то есть на выходе должно получиться:

```
        pd.DataFrame([{'id': 1, 'b': 1, 'd': 0},
                      {'id': 1, 'b': 2, 'd': 0},
                      {'id': 1, 'b': 2, 'd': 1},
                      {'id': 1, 'b': 2, 'd': 0},
                      {'id': 1, 'b': 2, 'd': 0},
                      {'id': 1, 'b': 2, 'd': 0},
                      {'id': 1, 'b': 4, 'd': 0}])
```

P.S. в каждом id только одна строка, где b == 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно попробовать так:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([{'id': 1, 'b': 1, 'd': 0},
                  {'id': 1, 'b': 2, 'd': 0},
                  {'id': 1, 'b': 2, 'd': 1},
                  {'id': 1, 'b': 2, 'd': 0},
                  {'id': 1, 'b': 2, 'd': 0},
                  {'id': 1, 'b': 2, 'd': 0},
                  {'id': 1, 'b': 4, 'd': 0},
                  {'id': 2, 'b': 1, 'd': 1},
                  {'id': 2, 'b': 2, 'd': 0},
                  {'id': 2, 'b': 2, 'd': 0},
                  {'id': 2, 'b': 2, 'd': 0},
                  {'id': 2, 'b': 2, 'd': 0},
                  {'id': 2, 'b': 2, 'd': 1},
                  {'id': 2, 'b': 4, 'd': 0},])

res = df.groupby('id').filter(lambda x: (x[x['b']==1]["d"].ne(1)))
```

res:

```
   id  b  d
0   1  1  0
1   1  2  0
2   1  2  1
3   1  2  0
4   1  2  0
5   1  2  0
6   1  4  0
```

Comment: Спасибо. Помогло)